# Can't initialise tooltip after upgrading from 3.3.1 to latest version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, model-view-controller

We have an old product which is written with .NET MVC. Now we are trying to upgrade all the dependecies to the latest version.
We are using jQuery and jQuery.UI.Combined from NuGet.
Now I have a problem with jQuery in this project.

I've updated jQuery 3.3.1, jQuery.UI.Combined 1.12.* to the latest version, but now I get the error

*jQuery.Deferred exception:
jQuery(...)tooltip is not a function*
.

and some functions included in the code are also not recognised.
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qvRd.png)

here is how i register bundles in Bundles.cs:

```
            bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                      "~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                      "~/Scripts/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.de.min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.en.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

layout.js

```html
function InitializeTooltip() {
    jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}
```

_layout.cshtml

```html
<head>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
</head>
```

I have made sure that jQuery is loaded before all bundles.

I have made sure that jQuery is loaded before all bundles.
I've already tried moving the bundles back and forth or declaring and initialising them differently, but that didn't help.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The error you reported indicates that a jQuery UI Library is not loading. Please review your resulting HTML and confirm that it's all loading the JavaScript as it should. Maybe something else is conflicting with UI.